# How to take name of user admin in html

Tags: python, django, view, model

I try to take the name of author for published article.

in model

```
class Artigo(models.Model):
  autor = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete = models.CASCADE)
  titulo = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
  categoria = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
  conteudo = models.TextField()
  data_publicacao = models.DateTimeField(
    default = timezone.now
    )

def publicacao(self):
    self.data_publicacao = timezone.now()
    self.save()

def __str__(self):
    return self.titulo
```

in view

```
def noticias(request):
 artigos = Artigo.objects.filter(data_publicacao__lte = timezone.now()).order_by('data_publicacao')
return render(request, 'noticia/noticias.html', {'artigos':artigos})
```

in html

```
<h1>Noticias</h1>
{% for artigo in artigos %}
  <div>
    <h1><a href ="">{{ artigo.titulo}} </a> </h1>
    <p>{{ artigo.conteudo }}</p>
    <p>Publicado em: {{ artigo.data_publicacao }}</p>
    <p>{{ artigo.autor.username }}</p>*
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

this **{{ artigo.autor.username }}** dosen't work. I have error : Exception Value:  invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'ElFrances'

I don't know how to take the name of author or other detail

Comment: That error is not coming from this code. Please show the full traceback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i think you want to use django users and that's allright but here are some details

see on model first you need to import it:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```

then you do this

```
class Artigo(models.Model):
autor = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

tell me if that works for you

also does the * in

{{ artigo.autor.username }}

* 
is for something? perhaps try deleting it

Comment: One author can write many articles that's why the the relationship of author and articles is one to many relationship.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `artigo.autor` only?

Comment: the problem disappears but the user name does not appear. But tank's for helping !

Answer (score 0):

You are getting error due to this line

```
autor = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete = models.CASCADE)
```

Instead of above line replace with this line

```
autor = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
```

And also use select_related for Query performance because when you fetch author details you again hit the database.

[See official Django Documentation for select_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.select_related)